# get_secure_cookie("XX") inside tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler

Tags: cookies, tornado

I have a tornado app with both `tornado.web.RequestHandler` and  `tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler`. I set a secure cookie within the request hander. Within the following class I get the cookie (simplified for illustrations purposes):

```
class SessionHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
   def open(self):
      print(self.get_secure_cookie("XX"))
```

This works to get the cookie. I'm happy about this but I don't understand why this works  the get_secure_cookie() method is RequestHandler Class. Can someone please tell me the relationship here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the WebSocketHandler inherits from tornado.web.RequestHandler

```
class WebSocketHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
```

I didn't think that would be the case.

Comment: WebSocket starts as a HTTP request and gets upgraded to a WebSocket socket. Because it still receives a HTTP request string and HTTP headers (which include cookies), inheritance from RequestHandler makes sense.